# HTML5 Filesystems API - Letting Users Save Files to Their Actual Filesystem

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

I am aware that the [HTML5 Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) gives you access to a sandboxed file system. Let's say I write a file to the filesystem. Is it possible to let the user save that file to their actual file system? I would like to be able to tell the user where the file is written so that they may access it but that does not seem to be possible.

My only idea is to [read the file as a data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29) and make a hyperlink that the user can save, but that has scalability issues in terms of file size.

Comment: Note really. You can create a local filesystem path based on browser though (possibly) that they could go to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the URL obtained from the `toURL` method as the value for a link's href attribute, which link in addition has a [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute. Clicking on the link will then prompt the user to save the contents on her filesystem.

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept your answer since I can't accept mine for two days. ｡◕‿◕｡

Comment: And what if I want to save 1000000 files into "visible" local directory? E.g. when my app is used to batch-resize 1000000 images?

Comment: @IvanKuckir hmm, I'd create an archive and provide a download link for that. There's zip.js that can help you with that. I never used it though. http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

Comment: Thanks, but so many images may not fit into RAM all at the same time :(

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [MDN - Basic Concepts About the Filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File_APIs/Filesystem/Basic_Concepts_About_the_Filesystem_API):

> You can, however, export a file from a web app to a desktop app. For example, you can use the File API, create a blob, redirect an iframe to the blob, and invoke the download manager.

Also, [the very page I linked to before](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-filesystemurls) discusses `FileEntry`'s `toURL()` method which returns a url in the form of `filesystem:`.

[Here is another article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) on how to make the browser download a file from a url.